# On slide-out animation make opacity 0.5

Tags: css, animation, css-animations

This is my CSS:

```
.sliding-background {
  height: 300px;
  width: 5000px;
  animation: slide 30s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes slide {
  0% {
   transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate3d(-1692px, 0, 0);
  }
}
```

as you can imagine the final result is slide for images.

My question:
I want it so that when the image/element goes out from screen the `opacity` becomes `0.5`.

Answer (score 0):

your description is a bit short and the code here is missing html, so that we could exactly see what is your intention and what is your problem.

BUT! :)

The shortest answer looking at your code and your question is to edit the animation keyframes a little bit.

Just end your animation not on 100% but earlier, like 80%.
Then the last 20% is your opacity animation.
Just remember to set a proper animation time, so that it won't be too fast :)

```
@keyframes slide {
  0% {
   transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
  80% {
    transform: translate3d(-1692px, 0, 0);
  }
  100%{
    transform: translate3d(-1692px, 0, 0);
    opacity:.5;
  }
}
```

the 80% is just my suggestion, you can use whatever you like - just be sure to leave some % of keyframes for your opacity change.

Remember to use vendor prefixes for the transform and keyframes!